# How to use EOF to end scanf loop?

Tags: c, scanf

I need to receive numbers until I press enter, I've tried to compare the returned value of the scanf with EOF but it keeps asking me to enter more numbers(infinite loop) :

```
int fail=0, late=0, avg=0, i=0, last=0, current, permission, difference;
while(scanf(" %d", &current) != EOF)
{
    permission = (current < last);
    difference = ((last - current) >= 30);
    fail += difference*permission;
    late += permission;
    avg += (last - current)*(permission);
    last = last*(permission) + current*(!permission);
}
```

Any suggestions.

 thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the scanf specification says that it will read and ignore any whitespace characters. Also, the specification says that EOF is returned only in case of an input failure before any data could be successfully read. You can read it by yourself [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/).

I would suggest using other reading functions as mentioned in other answers. Still, if you have to live and die with that scanf loop, perhaps you can add inside, at the bottom, the following code:

```
if (getchar() == '\n') break;
```

It should work if your input are only numbers and it's just a way to make it work around.

Comment: Note that after all, what it's doing is breaking of an infinite loop since scanf returns the number of items successfully read (which would not be zero)

Answer (score 0):

One issue you are having is that the documentation for scanf says that most format conversions skip whitespace.  (This includes carriage return and newline.)

One option is to read a character at a time and then make some numbers.  In this way you could catch any bogus input.  You could also differentiate between inline whitespace (space and tabs) and line terminating whitespace (CR and NL).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using linux you can stop your while loop if you enter `CTRL+D`

EOF = <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (for Linux)

EOF = <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (for Windows)